# Don't prepend wordpress base url to image paths

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm programmatically adding image attachments to posts, however I'm not uploading the image, just storing the full url which is hosted on a CDN e.g.

`https://i.atcdn.co.uk/imgser-uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=fa348829bc924e28a649624e52f7191e&width=1024&height=768`

However when the template is rendered it prepends the base url e.g.

`http://localhost:8888/wordpress/https://i.atcdn.co.uk/imgser-uk/imgser-uk/servlet/media.jpg?id=fa348829bc924e28a649624e52f7191e&width=1024&height=768`

I'm trying to hook into the media attachments to sort this out but I can't get anything to work.

Are there any filter hooks available so I can not prepend the base url if the path starts with `r'http[s]?://'` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the upload directory to point to the CDN. Try adding the following code to your functions.php file

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'get_images_from_cnd' );

function get_images_from_cnd( $args ) {
  $args['baseurl'] = 'https://i.atcdn.co.uk/imgser-uk/imgser-uk/servlet';
  return $args;
}
```